# Troubleshooting import.io

Tags: web-scraping, import.io

I am using import.io to scrape information from various websites for a research project. While it usually does a very good job, it occasionally outputs a blank page within the scraper interface and I am not able to select any data or otherwise interact with the website.

Is there anything I can do to manipulate the URL or the site itself so that I can access its data? There aren't any issues with accessing the website normally and I feel like there should be a workaround, but I'm a little inexperienced and haven't been able to figure anything out. I've tried using different browsers and toggling the script and styles options on import.io.

Comment: Can you share the URL that you are trying to get data from?  And specify the data that you are trying to extract.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your response. I am trying to extract the information in the main table on [this website](http://moud.gov.in/cms/telephone-directory.php)